# Select XAML TextBox in StackPanel using TextBox's Index

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, win-universal-app, stackpanel

I have the following code:

```
//All elements edited below have already been defined in MainPage.xaml    

int index = Window_1_Document_Page_1.Children.IndexOf(sender as TextBox);
//Window_1_Document_Page_1.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

Window_1_Document_Page_1.Children.Remove(sender as TextBox);
```

Before deleting `sender as TextBox`, how do I set the focus to the TextBox above it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `TraversalRequest` is what you search for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.input.traversalrequest_members%28v=vs.85%29.ASPx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but this should work:

```
        //Get index of control you want to delete
        int index = Panel.Children.IndexOf(sender as TextBox);

        //find textbox with lower index
        var control = Panel.Children.LastOrDefault(c => c is TextBox && Panel.Children.IndexOf(c) < index);
        //check if a control was found
        if (control != null)
        {
            //set focus
            var textbox = control as TextBox;
            textbox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }

        Panel.Children.Remove(sender as TextBox);
```