# Select element within StackPanel by index C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

How can I select an element for manipulation by its `Stackpanel` index?

Earlier on, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240682/select-xaml-textbox-in-stackpanel-using-textboxs-index) question has been asked, but the solution does not work in window applications, but only in Universal Windows Applications.

Comment: What aspect doesn't work? Getting the index or something else?

Comment: What's wrong with just `yourPanel.Children[index_you_need]`? Can you demonstrate an example of your *exact* problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Children` property. It returns a property with an indexer that you can access with an index. The following sample contains two TextBlocks in a StackPanel and sets the text of the second one to another value in the constructor:

### XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnl">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="World" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var txt = (TextBlock)pnl.Children[1];
    txt.Text = "Moon";
}
```

The relevant part for accessing the child by index is: `pnl.Children[index];`