# uwp How I click to get index Children of canvas

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to get Children index from canvas for remove select childern

```
  private  void Clear_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
```

`ImageHolder.Children.Remove(ImageHolder.Children[1]);
    }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select element within StackPanel by index C# XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523569/select-element-within-stackpanel-by-index-c-sharp-xaml)

Comment: Please provide more information, such as why you should do this. Maybe in addition to deleting elements, you can also set the element's `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Answer (score 0):

> uwp How I click to get index Children of canvas

You could add `Tapped` event for your control where in the Canvas. Then get index with the following code .

```
private void Abr_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var index = TestCanvas.Children.IndexOf(sender as AppBar);
}
```